# Can different extensions of ZF have contradictory consequences for first-order arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, foundations

My question is basically, does there exist a statement X independent of ZF such that ZF + X implies a statement P of first-order arithmetic, but ZF + not X implies not P?

Now X cannot be the axiom of constructibility due to Schoenfield's absoluteness theorem, which states that the axiom of constructibility, and thus its consequences like the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis, can't be used to prove any statement of first-order arithmetic that you couldn't already prove using ZF:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem

Also, there are examples like Con(ZF), but they're not really interesting, because obviously Con(ZF) is a true statement assuming that ZF is sound.  So I'm specifically looking for statements X whose truth value cannot be deduced from the assumption that ZF is sound.

So perhaps a preliminary question should be, does there exist any statement independent of ZF which can prove statements of first-order arithmetic that ZF can't prove, but whose truth value does not follow from the assumption that ZF is sound?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT:  This is based on [a question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467017/do-the-axiom-of-choice-and-its-negation-have-contradictory-consequences-for-arit) from Math.Stackexchange:

EDIT 2:  Just to clarify, when I said "does not follow from the assumption that ZF is sound", I was speaking metamathematically, I wasn't talking about reasoning within the language of ZF.  I meant that we shouldn't be obliged to believe either X or its negation just because we believe that the axioms of ZF are true.  The axiom of choice is an example of such a statement: if we accept that the axioms of ZF are true, that doesn't compel us to accept either the axiom of choice or its negation.  But unfortunately, the axiom of choice doesn't have any new consequences for first-order arithmetic, outside of what ZF already allows us to prove.  So I want a statement like that that does have consequences for first-order arithmetic.

Still, if people find it too informal to talk about metamathematical reasoning, we can make things more precise by defining the truth predicate of ZF within NBG set theory, as shown in theorem 1 of [(Mostowski 1950)](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm37/fm37110.pdf).  Or, if @JoelDavidHamkins is right and we can't define a truth predicate within NBG, I'm happy to define the truth predicate within Morse-Kelley set theory instead.  But however we formalize it, I hope my intent is clear: I want a statement X such that mathematicians who agree that the axioms of ZF are true can still disagree about whether statement X is true.

EDIT 3:  I've come to realize that consistency statements Con(T) don't satisfy what I'm trying to ask, because the only warrant of their independence from ZF is that we assume that the underlying theory T is in fact consistent.  Because if the theory were inconsistent, then the falsehood of Con(T) could be proven in ZF and even in PA.  The reason for that is that consistency statements are all Pi_1 statements, and every false Pi_1 statement can be proven wrong in PA and thus ZF.  So I want the arithmetical statement P to be higher up in the arithmetical hierarchy than Pi_1.

Now, as @WillSawin has pointed out, it's easy to show that there are truths of first-order arithmetic that are independent of ZF + (All Pi_1 truths), because otherwise an oracle who could decide Pi_1 truths would be able to decide all truths of first-order arithmetic, which is obviously wrong.  So we know that such a statement exists.  But I would prefer to have a concrete statement, not just a proof that a statement exists.

And more importantly, while I do want P to be a statement of first-order arithmetic, I would prefer that X not be a statement of arithmetic.  I want X to be a set-theoretic statement that's not an arithmetic statement, something like the axiom of choice, the continuum hypothesis, or a large cardinal axiom.  The fundamental intent of my question is, can there be an unfalsifiable disagreement about which set theory is correct, which leads to an unfalsifiable disagreement about which statements of first-order arithmetic are correct?  As noted above, Schoenfield's absolute theorem rules out the axiom of choice  and the continuum hypothesis, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467017/do-the-axiom-of-choice-and-its-negation-have-contradictory-consequences-for-arit/467024#467024) to my Math.SE question suggests that large cardinals won't work either.  So does anyone know any non-arithmetical set-theoretic statement, independent of ZF, which implies a non-Pi_1 statement of first-order arithmetic that's independent of ZF?

Comment: Amazing. [Two hours of waiting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467017/) between cross posting your question. You should at least point out that this was posted on m.SE and provide a link.

Comment: Are you sure that you know what sort of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Regarding your third edit, how can you say that you want X to be not arithmetic, given that it must be provably equivalent to P?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It's fine if it's equivalent to a statement of arithmetic, I just don't want it to be one.  If there's something like a large cardinal axiom which turns out to be equivalent to a statement in the language of first-order arithmetic, that would be fine with me.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins (cont'd)  Perhaps a good preliminary question would be, how would you construct a statement of first-order arithmetic that is independent of ZF + (All Pi_1 truths), and which does not follow in MK from the assumption that ZF is sound?

Comment: As I mention in my comments on my answer, Con(KM+True $\Pi^0_1$) is such a statement. (And it seems to me that KM proves "ZF is sound".)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins As far as I can tell, Con(KM + all true Pi_1 statements) is equivalent to the statement that KM is Pi_1 sound.  But if KM were not Pi_1 sound, then it would prove some false Pi_1 statement, and since that statement is Pi_1, KM would also disprove it, so KM would be inconsistent.  So if I'm not mistaken, Con(KM + all true Pi_1 statements) is equivalent to Con(KM), and Con(KM) is Pi_1.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Each new edit makes the question more and more confused. And you are mistaken in your last comment. You may want to read the relevant sections of **Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic**, where most of this is covered carefully.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo  Thanks, I may read it.  But could you tell me what's wrong with the reasoning in my last comment?

Comment: Read the reference, it may be more productive.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo If it's not too much trouble, could you tell me what part to read?  http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926

Comment: "if @JoelDavidHamkins is right and we can't define a truth predicate within NBG" This is not a matter of opinion (and he's right).

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan: Con(KM+True $\Pi^0_1$) says that KM is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound (or equivalently, $\Pi^0_2$-sound) rather than $\Pi^0_1$-sound.

Comment: @EmilJerabek Doesn't Con(KM + all Pi_1 truths) assert that no theorems of KM contradict a Pi _1 truth?  How is that different from saying that KM is Pi_1 sound?

Comment: KM contradicts a $\Pi^0_1$ truth if it proves the negation of said truth. The negation of a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence is $\Sigma^0_1$, so in other words, KM proves a false $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence. Saying that this does not happen thus amounts to all $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences provable in KM being true, i.e., that KM is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound.

Answer (score 6):

Since you want ZF+X to prove P and ZF+$\neg$X to prove $\neg$P, it follows that X is equivalent to P. So basically, you are asking for an arithmetic assertion that is independent of ZF, but which satisfies your requirement that it "not follow from the assumption that ZF is sound".

Of course, there are plentiful arithmetic assertions that are independent of ZF, provided that ZF is consistent, such as the Rosser sentence for ZF. But presumably this doesn't satisfy your requirement.

If large cardinals are consistent, then we get more examples. For example, Con(ZF + there is a measurable cardinal) is thought by many set theorists to be true, and in this case it is not provable in ZF, since it implies Con(ZF). But one cannot deduce that it is true just from the assumption that ZF proves only true arithmetic assertions, since if ZF is consistent, then it is consistent with ZF that this assertion is false, yet ZF has an $\omega$-model and hence is arithmetically sound. (This is because the assumption that ZF has an  $\omega$-model has weaker consistency strength than a measurable cardinal.)

This reasoning shows that for any consistent theory T whose consistency strength is stronger than an $\omega$-model of ZF (and this includes all of the usual large cardinals), then Con(T) will be an example of a statement independent of ZF yet not deducible merely from the fact that ZF is arithmetically sound.

**Update.** You have explained that you want to find an arithmetic statement independent of ZF and not provable from the assumption that ZF is sound, where this is formalized in Kelley-Morse set theory.

Indeed, the soundness of ZF is formalizable in KM, since this theory proves the existence of a full satisfaction class for first-order truth. And so in KM we can formulate the assertion $S$ that says "every theorem of ZF is true". Indeed, S is a theorem of KM, which can be seen by induction on the length of proofs, since we have a truth predicate for first-order truth.

So the example sentence $P$ you seek could just be Con(KM). If true, this will be independent of ZF, and you cannot prove it from the assumption that ZF is sound, since then you could prove it in KM, which you cannot by the incompleteness theorem.

(But since you've made the move from ZF to KM, one might think you now want to consider statements P independent of KM, which are not deducible from the "soundness" of KM, and we would be back to the essence of the earlier objections, one level up.)

Comment: Yes, I want examples which you can't deduce the truth value of simply by assuming that ZF is sound.

Comment: Joel, nice example on the consistency of large cardinals. I feel that this example is still somehow "cheating" and misses the examples the OP is after; but I'm getting a vibe that maybe the OP doesn't know what he is looking for exactly either.

Comment: Keshav, my edit show that there are many example arising from the large cardinal hiearchy. Basically, any true assertion of the form Con(ZF+ $\exists$ large cardinal) will be independent of ZF, but not deducible merely from the arithmetic soundness of ZF, since the consistency strength exceeds the strength of the existence of an $\omega$-model of ZF, which implies the arithmetic soundness of ZF.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I didn't mean arithmetic soundness, I meant soundness in general; I want a statement whose truth value is not a consequence of the assumption that the axioms of ZF are true.  If ZF is sound, then it's consistent, so ZF + there is a measurable cardinal is consistent, so Con(ZF + there is a measurable cardinal) is true.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of truth shows that we can have no formal concept of "true" that is expressible within our theory. So you'll have to be more precise about exactly what you mean.

Comment: That is, while we are able to express in set theory that a given theory T is arithmetically sound, or sound for assertions about hereditarily countable sets, or about $H_{\omega_2}$ and so on, we are not able to formulate the notion of a set theory $T$ being "sound" in general, in the sense of having only true consequences. A straightforward way to saying it would use a truth predicate, which we have none by Tarski's theorem.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I'm not trying to define truth or soundness within the language of set theory.  I'm speaking metamathematically about the soundness of ZF.  I want a statement X which, metamathematically speaking, is not consequence of the soundness of ZF.  (And neither is the negation of X.)  The axiom of choice is an example of such a statement, because you can't conclude either choice or its negation from the assumption that the axioms of ZF are true.  But unfortunately, the axiom of choice can't prove any statements of first-order arithmetic that ZF can't already prove.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So you are using an informal metalanguage and assume a Platonic notion of sets and soundness of ZF means that these sets are a “model” of ZF? Well, if your notion of soundness is not defined by a formal system but a philosophical notion, then what is an “implication” of this kind of soundness? And how should we tell whether there is such an implication? (and even philosophically this notion is questionable)

Comment: Ny problem with your example Con(KM) and @TheUser's example Con(NBG + "ZF is sound"), is that if they're true, then yes they are independent of ZF.  But if they're false, i.e. if the underlying theory is inconsistent, then they can be proven false in ZF and even in PA.  The same goes for any consistency statement, so I want something other than a consistency statement, something that must be independent of ZF regardless of whether it's true or false.  The axiom of choice meets that condition, but again it proves no new arithmetical truths.  So I want something that does.

Comment: I think we can prove the existence of an undecidable statement that is not decided by  any true consistency statement by considering the theory ZF + all true $\Pi_1$ statements. We just need an arithmetic statement that is undecidable in this theory. Such a statement exists, because if it didn't, a Turing machine with a Halting oracle could decide truth values of arithmetic statements. But it is known that it cannot.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But if Con(NBG+“ZF is sound”) is false, then your assumption of soundness of ZF cannot hold.

Comment: @TheUser No, that's not true.  The inconsistency of NBG + "ZF is sound" would imply that NBG is unsound, but I don't see how it would imply that ZF is unsound.  In any case, even if you're right, then that's all the more reason to reject Con(NBG+“ZF is sound”) as the kind of statement I'm looking for, because its truth value would follow from the assumption that ZF is sound.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Assuming your formal definition of soundness of ZF in NBG a contradiction in NBG+“ZF is sound” would of course imply that NBG proves that ZF is not sound. And I cannot imagine formal formulations of soundness with weaker consistency assumptions.

Comment: @Keshav, I'm sorry that you don't like the Con(KM) example, although I believe it does answer the question that you've asked. Indeed, it is my impression that you've received several thoughtful answers here to your various questions, as well as help in formulating your intention...

Comment: @TheUser Yes, an inconsistency in NBG + "ZF is sound" would imply that NBG proves that ZF is not sound, but that wouldn't imply that ZF is not sound.  It's certainly possible for ZF to be sound and for NBG to imply that ZF is not sound.  All that would mean is that NBG is not sound.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Then you would have to give another definition of soundness in a different system than NBG. And NBG is already _very_ mild, it is a conservative extension and they are equiconsistent. Furthermore, you can play the same game in any extension of ZF where you can speak about soundness.

Comment: @TheUser I don't quite understand what you're saying, but we may be having a misunderstanding due to me not phrasing my objection to consistency statements well enough.  I think my new edit to my question may clarify things.  The problem is that consistency statements are Pi_1, and Pi_1 statements can always be disproven if they're wrong, in both ZF and PA.  So a consistency statement is only independent of ZF is in fact true.  (to be continued)

Comment: (cont'd) So to sum up, I want a statement X such that (1). NBG doesn't prove that "ZF is sound" implies X and NBG doesn't prove that "ZF is sound" implies not X; (2).  ZF would not prove either X or not X if X were false; (3).  ZF + X proves a statement of arithmetic that ZF by itself doesn't prove.  Now admittedly, (2) is a bit vague, but for all practical purposes it means that X shouldn't be a Pi_1 statement.

Comment: Well, I'm finding your question to be a moving target. For your latest version, in the previous comment, it seems that you can use Con(KM+true $\Pi^0_1$), meaning the consistency of the theory of KM with the collection of $\Pi^0_1$ sentences that happen to be true. Note that this consistency assertion is no longer $\Pi^0_1$, since the theory is not computable, but it is $\Pi^0_2$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins See my comment to my question, where I give an argument that seems to show that Con(KM + all true Pi_1 statements) is actually Pi_1.

Answer (score 6):

Let me, for a moment, follow Joel in taking "sound" to mean arithmetically sound, i.e., all arithmetical statements provable in ZF are true. That fact is expressible as a sentence $S$ in the language of set theory. Then Con(ZFC $+\ S$) is true but not deducible from the soundness assumption $S$.

Now let me suppose instead that you intended soundness to mean more than arithmetical soundness, say, for example, that all ZF-provable statements of higher-order arithmetic are true. That's also expressible as a sentence in the language of set theory, so the same idea as above still gives an example.

To escape from this sort of example, one needs to interpret "soundness" in a way that can't be expressed in the language of ZF.  For example, it might mean that every sentence provable in ZF is true in the full universe of sets.  Truth in the universe is not expressible in the language of ZF, so you don't get cheap examples as above.  But by eliminating the cheap answer, this version of soundness raises questions about the very meaning of the question.  What does it mean for something to "follow from" soundness, when soundness can't be expressed in the language of set theory? You'd need to explain (at least) what sort of deductions are intended by "follow".

Comment: I am indeed talking about soundness in the sense of every theorem of ZF being true, or equivalently the axioms of ZF all being true.  When I was talking about following from soundness, I was speaking metamathematically,  I meant that there should be no way to conclude metamathematically that X or its negation is true from the assumption that ZF is sound.  Or if you feel that talking about metamathematically reasoning is too informal, then here's a way to make it more precise: I think the truth predicate for ZF is expressible in NBG set theory, so we can talk about proving X using that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, NBG does not prove the existence of a first-order truth predicate, although KM does. In this case, you could use Con(KM), which if true, is independent of ZF and implies the consistency of a standard model of ZF, which is elementary in V. Thus, it is similar to the other examples we have here.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I just put a link in my question to a paper by Mostowski, which seems to show that the truth predicate of ZF is expressible in NBG.  Am I interpreting it incorrectly?  Also, about Con(KM), is it possible for ZF to be sound and yet KM to be inconsistent?  In other words, if someone found an inconsistency in Morse-Kelly set theory tomorrow, would that mean that the axioms of ZF can't all be true?

Comment: To my (quick) reading of that theorem, Mostowski does not present a full satisfaction class, but rather a class that he proves works for any particular formula, as a scheme. This will result in merely a partial satisfaction class, as GBC will not in general prove that every formula is covered by it (and it cannot prove this, as this would mean GBC proves the consistency of ZF, which is impossible). If you google "partial satisfaction classes" you will find out more; most of the material is for models of arithmetic, but much of the theory carries over to set theory.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have had a look at the paper: You are right, there is a truth predicate, but what you call “soundness” of ZF (i. e. the statement “every axiom of ZF is true”) cannot be proved in NBG. However, in an ω-model of NBG ZF is “sound”.

Comment: @TheUser Why does it matter that the soundness of ZF can't be proved in NBG?  At least it can be defined in NBG, so within NBG we can still see what statements follow from the soundness of ZF.  So does there exist some statement independent of ZF which doesn't follow from the soundness of ZF (and it's negation doesn't either), such that it has consequences for first-order arithmetic that ZF itself doesn't have?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins If NBG could prove that every formula is covered by the proposed truth predicate, how would that allow it to prove the consistency of ZF?

Comment: So consider the arithmetic statement Con(NBG+“NBG has an ω-model”), this cannot be proved using “soundness” of ZF. Or simply Con(NBG+“ZF is sound”).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan “how would that allow it to prove the consistency of ZF” You would have proved that V is a model of ZF, thus Con(ZF). Since NBG in conservative, this would imply that Con(ZF) is provable in ZF.

Comment: @TheUser How would being able to prove in NBG that the proposed truth predicate for ZF works for all formulas allow you to prove the existence of a model of ZF?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Not by the specification, but by the assumption “every axiom of ZF is true (in V)”. I think that that is more or less what Joel called “every formula is covered by it”. @ Joel Or what did you mean?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Do the examples Con(NBG+“ZF is sound”) and Con(KM) satisfy you?

Comment: @TheUser I assuned that Joel was talking about the statement that the proposed truth predicate works for all formulas in the language of ZF.  And I was asking why NBG proving that statement would imply that NBG proves the consistency of ZF.

Comment: What do you mean by “works”?

Comment: @TheUser The proposed truth predicate V(n) works for a given n if V(n) is equivalent to the formula coded by n.  So the question is, does NBG prove that for all n, the proposed truth predicate works.

Comment: @TheUser No, those consistency statements don't satisfy me; see the comment I just wrote in Joel's answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But then “working” is a property in your metalanguage, it cannot be expressed in NBG, thus you cannot ask whether its provability in NBG would imply anything.

Comment: @TheUser I thought that Joel was saying that NBG can only prove for each formula that the proposed truth predicate works for that formula, and that you need KM to prove a single statement that says that a proposed truth predicate works for all formulas.  But if you're right, then what distinguishes NBG and KM as far as the definability of a truth predicate?

Comment: Since the language of NBG is exactly the same as KM, defining "ZF is sound" in NBG is the same as defining it in KM. What one needs to say is: there is a truth predicate for first-order truth (this is provable in KM but not in NBG) and every theorem of ZF is true.

Comment: I suppose it would suffice to say: there is a partial truth predicate, with respect to which every theorem of ZF is true.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Why can't the existence of a truth-predicate for truth in the language of ZF be proven in NBG?  You said that if it were possible, then NBG would prove the consistency of ZF, but why is that?

Comment: NBG cannot prove the existence of a truth predicate, if it is consistent, because some models of NBG have only first-order definable classes, and Tarski's theorem implies that there can never be a first-order definable truth predicate.

Comment: Meanwhile, if $S$ is a full satisfaction class in NBG, then one can prove by induction on the lengths of proofs that whatever theory it shows as "true" must be consistent. In particular, if it shows ZF as true, then Con(ZF) holds.

Answer (score 2):

Harvey Friedman has discovered a number of arithmetic (actually, $\Pi^0_1$) statements of combinatorics which are independent of $ZFC$. This is part of his ongoing research project, "Boolean Relation Theory" (see http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/BoolRelnThyNotes100601.pdf).

Now, since these statements follow from (in fact, are equivalent to) the consistency of large cardinal propositions, it's not clear that they are what you are looking for; but you may still find them interesting.

Comment: In fact, it is clear that they are not.

Comment: @Andres: you're right, I didn't read the question carefully enough. If the OP says I should, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I don't think you should. This is an interesting and valuable observation, and illustrates a subtlety of the question.